# A question about HOD

Tags: set-theory

Suppose $\phi$ is a sentence in the language of ZFC such that ZFC proves $\phi^{HOD}$. I need to show that ZFC already proves $\phi$. Could you give any hints? Thank you!

Comment: ...What is HOD?

Comment: @Charles: The class of hereditarily ordinal definable sets.

Comment: Am I missing something? We may write down a formula $\phi$ s.t. $ZFC$ proves $\phi^{HOD}$ is an ordinal definable surjection $(ORD \rightarrow V)^{HOD}$. As such a formula witnessed $V = HOD$, this doesn't follow from $ZFC$ and therefore seems to contradict your claim.

Comment: @Stefan There is the subtle issue that $\mathrm{HOD}$ may not satisfy $V=\mathrm{HOD}$, so getting such a $\phi$ is not that simple.

Comment: @Miha Oh, right. I know very little on the subject and thought that I might miss some subtlety. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 8):

This might be overkill for this particular problem, but the fact is that we can do class forcing over any model $V$ to produce an extension $V[G]$ such that $\mathrm{HOD}^{V[G]}=V$. This answers your question, since it shows that any model at all is a $\mathrm{HOD}$ of something.

The forcing is closely related to the McAloon-style coding forcing to get $V=\mathrm{HOD}$ and there is a nice exposition in [Fuchs, Hamkins, Reitz: Set-Theoretic Geology](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.4776/). The basic idea is to identify a class of nicely behaved cardinals $\delta$ and consider the poset $\mathbb{Q}_\delta$ which generically chooses to make the GCH either hold or fail at $\delta$. The final poset is then the set support $\mathrm{Ord}$-length product $\prod_\delta\mathbb{Q}_\delta$. A density argument shows that any set (of ordinals) in $V$ is coded into the GCH pattern of the final extension and so $V$ is contained in the extension's $\mathrm{HOD}$. The other inclusion follows by a homogeneity argument (there is a slight twist from the way one usually does this since the $\mathbb{Q}_\delta$ are not actually homogeneous).

Comment: I don't think this is overkill, since I don't know any other way to prove the conclusion except by proving that every ZFC model is the HOD of another ZFC model.

Comment: For the original reference to the result in the first paragraph, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/222497/6085).