# Using a forcing extension $V[G]$ to determine properties of $V$.

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

It is well known that you can use forcing to change the truth value of various sentences ($CH$, $\Diamond$, et cetera). However, often when performing such a construction over a model $V$, the action is generally in $V[G]$ (or some inner model thereof - as when we violate $AC$ in $HOD(x)^{V[G]}$); we want to figure out what goes on in $V[G]$ for the purposes of, say, a relative consistency proof.

There are constructions, however, that also tell us about what goes on in $V$ (possibly in relation to $V[G]$), as when we consider embeddings of the form $j: V \longrightarrow M \subseteq V[G]$. Such embeddings can have quite small critical points (even as small as $\omega_1$), giving us a new perspective on the small uncountable sets of our original model $V$.

My question:

Are there *other* forcing constructions (i.e. not generic embeddings) that tell us what the structure of our original model $V$ is like with respect to *uncountable* sets (so not in the trivial sense of showing the consistency of proof-codes in $V_\omega$) and how $V$ relates to $V[G]$? To put it another way, are there other constructions that allow us to see the structure of $V$ more clearly from $V[G]$?

Comment: You can never violate choice in $\rm HOD^\it M$, whenever $M$ is any model of ZF. You probably meant $\mathrm{HOD}(x)^{V[G]}$ which may or may not satisfy choice.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Apologies, posted in haste. Corrected.

Comment: That's a very nice question; but one reason it's a bit baffling is that usually when you do these forcing arguments in order to prove something, you already have some information about the universe and you use that structure in order to pick the right forcing.

Comment: Looking at your title, I thought of quoting some applications of generic ultrapowers to prove ZFC facts, but unfortunately you have ruled them out.

Comment: A powerful tool for deducing things about $V$ from facts in the forcing extension is Shoenfield absoluteness (although this doesn't quite satisfy your requirement about uncountability).

Comment: @MihaHabič What about showing that if $V \models \omega_1 = \omega_1^L$, then there is a $\Pi_1^1$ set which is uncountable and does not have a perfect subset? I think the easiest argument is assume otherwise and apply Schoenfield absoluteness in a forcing extension satisfying $\neg \text{CH}$.

Comment: The Shoenfield Absoluteness point is nice. Basically, anything that is downward absolute about uncountable sets will do to begin with. Thanks also Asaf for the point about what you start with; this seems right, most of the time we begin in a model with very specific combinatorial properties. @hot_queen, I'd be interested as to what you have in mind here, are you thinking of generic embeddings? Or something else?

Comment: Another nice source of examples (also maneuvering generic embeddings) involves large cardinals more directly. We can prove, for instance, that suitable large cardinals $\kappa$ imply the Lebesgue measurability of all sets of reals by using the large cardinals to obtain (in some forcing extension of V) an embedding of $L(\mathbb R)^V$ into the $L(\mathbb R)$ of an extension via $\mathrm{Col}(\kappa,<\omega_1)$. One can improve this and obtain generic absoluteness from optimal assumptions, but then it s not yet a generic embedding we produce, but rather a genericity iteration.

Comment: An [example](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1362453/462) in a different direction.

Comment: Looking at this question again, I wonder if Corollary 16 and Theorem 18 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.02165.pdf) are examples to what you were looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Examples using generic ultrapowers:

(1) (Gititk, Shelah) If there is a total extension of Lebesgue measure, then there is a Sierpinski set (non Lebesgue null set of size $\aleph_1$ each of whose null subsets is countable).

Proof sketch: Force with the null ideal of the total extension and let $j: V \to M \subseteq V[G]$ be the ultrapower embedding with critical point $\kappa$. Using a generic ultrapower argument, Gitik and Shelah have shown that this forcing must add at least $\aleph_1$ random reals. This set of random reals is also in $M$ and is a Sierpinski set. By elementarity, such a set also exists in $V$.

(2) For every set of reals there is a subset of the same outer measure avoiding rational distance.

Proof idea: Assume it fails and get the restriction of the null ideal to some non null set to be isomorphic to a product of random and Cohen forcing. Use generic ultrapowers to argue that this is impossible.

Example using Shoenfield absoluteness:

(3) (Mycielski) If $A$ is a compact subset of plane of positive area, then there exists perfect sets $P, Q$ such that $P$ has positive length and $P \times Q \subseteq A$.

Proof: See the following mathoverflow [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206282/under-neg-ch-have-countable-unions-of-rationally-independent-numbers-inner-m/206306#206306).

Answer (score 4):

My favorite family of examples come from the partition calculus. The original proof of the Baumgartner-Hajnal theorem $\omega_1\to (\alpha)^2_n$ for all finite $ n $ and all countable $\alpha $ appealed to the absoluteness of well-foundedness. The homogeneous set was found in an extension where $\mathsf{MA} $ holds, and that means that a certain ground-model tree is illfounded in the extension.

This idea has been used in a variety of similar results: In Schipperus's proof of the topological version of the Baumgartner-Hajnal theorem, in Todorcevic's proof of the extension of the BH result to non-special posets, in several of the partial results towards the conjecture $\omega_1\to (\alpha, n)^3$ for all countable $ \alpha $ and finite $ n $,  etc.